# Get the current field name

Tags: javascript

I called below function on the body and what I want is when I press anything in textbox it will alert me the name of the textbox and I want to check the name and then execute something. Checking name is working great in FF and not in IE. Thanks

```
<body bgcolor="#F2F2F2" OnKeyPress="return getFieldName(event);">
```

...

```
function getFieldName(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which,
    target = e.target || e.srcElement;
}
```

This works but `target.name` is not trappable in IE
for eg:

```
if (target.name == 'one') {
    //we can reach here is FF and Not in IE
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can know which element triggered the event by looking the `e.target` property (or `e.srcElement` for IE):

```
function getFieldName(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var key = e.keyCode || e.which,
      target = e.target || e.srcElement;

  alert(target.name);
  return (key != 13);
}
```

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/exeji3).

And give a look to this article:

- [JavaScript Event Delegation is Easier than You Think](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/)